# file is uploading but not getting response

Tags: php, json, encryption

I have wrote an script to upload pdf file which encrypt the name of the file and upload it to the server. The script is working properly but not getting json response can any body help me out.

Here is my code

```
<?php
//Turn off all error reporting
//error_reporting(0);
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");

 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "!@#$%^&*");
  /**
  * Returns an encrypted & utf8-encoded
   */
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key,  utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $encrypted_string;
}

 /**
  * Returns decrypted original string
  */
  function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return $decrypted_string;
}


 $fieldname = 'pdfFile';
 $targetdir = 'upload/';
 $desiredtype = 'application/pdf';
 $return=array(
'status'    =>    'false',
'message'    =>    'Pdf file not uploaded!'
 );

 if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_FILES[ $fieldname ] )){
try{

    $obj = (object)$_FILES[ $fieldname ];
    $name = $obj->name;
    $size = $obj->size;
    $tmp  = $obj->tmp_name;
    $type = $obj->type;
    $error= $obj->error;






    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $type == $desiredtype ){

        $encrypted_name = encrypt($name, ENCRYPTION_KEY);

        $destination = $targetdir . $encrypted_name;
        $url = "webservice.pixcelservice.com";
        if( file_exists( $destination ) ){

            $return['status']='false';
            $return['message']='File already exists!';
            $return['line']=__LINE__;

            clearstatcache();

        } else {

           if($res = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $destination )){

            chmod($destination, 0755);  
            $return['status']=$res ? 'true' : 'false';
            $return['message']=$res ? 'Pdf file uploaded successfully!' : 'Moving the file failed!';
            $return['path']="$url/$destination";

            }

     }

    } else {
        $return['status']='false';
        $return['message']='File upload error!';
        $return['line']=__LINE__;
    }
}catch( Exception $e ){
        $return['status']='false';
        $return['message']=$e->getMessage();
        $return['line']=__LINE__;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
exit( json_encode( $return ) );

 } else {
 exit( header( 'HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed',true, 405 ) );
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: 1. Blowfish should not be used in new work, use AES, even the author of Blowfish uses AES. 2. ECB mode does not use an IV, providing an IV to ECB mode makes no sense. 3. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.

Comment: buddy riht now i am in a confusion why m i not getting json response.. Can you please help me in that.

Comment: It does not make sense helping create an insecure system.